# What is use of content://com.android.contacts in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to know what is use of content://com.android.contacts in android.

And what it return means which type data from contact.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is uri for contacts database. In android the platform provides content provider layer (database) to provide applications with ready data. So like contacts , you can get media.image etc from this database.

To use this you need to query the database to get cursor.

For more read android content provider topic